# Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found when running a new project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Whenever I try to run any command related to php artisan or composer this error shows up:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Monolog\ResettableInterface' not found in path\to\project\root\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Logger.php on line 28

I open the file, and it points me to :

> class Logger implements LoggerInterface, ResettableInterface

I try to find the Logger interface and it's there.

I really can't find any other solutions and the ones recommended here by SO are outdated.

I use laravel 5.7 running composer version 1.8.0 on a xampp server with PHP 7.2.10 on Windows 10

Please feel free to ask more questions and I'll try to answer them without ruining my NDA.

Update: it works now thanks to that one person who answered.

Comment: Try removing the `vendor` folder & do a `composer update`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone needs this solution, you can do what [Saumini Navaratnam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4273867/saumini-navaratnam) suggested; removing the `vendor` folder and running `composer update` on the root folder. I, myself found another solution that might work and it is: running `composer update --no-dev` as the ResettableInterface came from a dev dependency. Weird, but it works fine now.

> Again this works only on Laravel 5.7, at least for now.